# Best way to do client side validation on a calendar control

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application in which in one of the views I have a calendar control.

I load the Kendo ui datepicker through javascript and by default it sets the current date.

How can we do a validation on the datepicker so that the user does not submit an empty value for the date?

Right now I have a server side validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the view:

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new {@onchange = "checkDate()"})

then at the end of form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkDate(){
     var Date = $('#Date').val();
       var matches = /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(Date);
    if (matches == null){
//Here you can add code to highlight, show error etc.
return false;
} 
}
</script>
```

`matches= /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})` is Regex, it be different for different date formats

Answer (score 0):

If you add an `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]` attribute asp.net mvc provides client side validation automatically that handled by jquery validate. Also you should have look [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) for setting different cultures.